# Prometheus metric protocol buffer in gRPC

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, prometheus, grpc

I am a relatively new user of gRPC and protobufs in general. I have the following protobuf definition:

```
service GrpcStreamingService {
    rpc SomeRPC (Empty) returns (stream Metric);
}

message Metric {
    int64 timestamp = 1;
    string family = 2;
    string uuid = 3;
    double value = 4;
}

message Empty {}
```

I recently discovered the type [`prometheus.Metric`](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/main/prometheus/metric.go) and I am wondering if I can stream this directly via gRPC instead of `message Metric`. If not, what would be the recommended way to stream prometheus metric objects in gRPC.

Thanks for your help.

Tried importing the file as follows:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option go_package = "github.com/influxdata/plugins/outputs/grpcstreaming/proto";
package proto;

import "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/proto";
```

Get the following errors on compiling:

```
github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus: File not found.
proto/service.proto: Import "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus" was not found or had errors.
```

Here is what I use for compilation:

```bash
protoc  --go_out=. \
                --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
                --go-grpc_out=require_unimplemented_servers=false:. \
                --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
                proto/service.proto
```

Update: so I've discovered a `dto` object in the prometheus library.

```golang
import (
    dto "github.com/prometheus/client_model/go"
)

metric = prometheus.NewMetricWithTimestamp(sample.Timestamp, metric)
            var m = &dto.Metric{}
            //godoc: Write encodes the Metric into a "Metric" Protocol Buffer data transmission object.
            metric.Write(m)
            if err := metric.Write(m); err != nil {
                log.Printf("[COLLECT]: ERROR IN WRITE_METRIC_TO_PROTO\n")
            }
            log.Printf("[COLLECT]: Gauge=%v | Timestamps=%v\n", m.Gauge.GetValue(), m.GetTimestampMs())
```

However, I still do not know a way to transmit this metric via an rpc.
On the receiving end of the RPC, I should be able to insert this metric into a prometheus instance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I'm unsure what the goal is in using gRPC which would help answer your question. I'm going to comment on your question as it's written.

Comment: Prometheus originally supported a [Protobuf exposition format](https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/main/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md#protobuf-format) that was abandoned **but** has been resurrected experimentally (e.g. see [Feature Flag: Native Histograms](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/feature_flags/#native-histograms).

Comment: I've **not** used this mechanism but the documentation suggests you can ingest (into Prometheus) protobuf-based metrics. It's unclear whether Prometheus also publishes (as a gRPC server) messages using this format. You'll need to investigate.

Comment: You can't `import "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/proto"` because the URL is invalid and does not point to protocol buffer sources. Prometheus does document protocol buffer sources ([`prompb`](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tree/main/prompb)) but you'll need to investigate how Prometheus supports protocol buffers and gRPC to understand how to use these.